# Can't Accessing client_secrets.json & Credentials.json file in Heroku

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, heroku

I'm trying to authorize Google Drive when I deploy my project to heroku.
I used to authorize my account this code which generate credentials.json file to let users access some file in my google drive for a long time:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth.LoadCredentialsFile('credentials.json')
if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile('credentials.json')
```

This works fine locally on my machine when I have the JSON file in the project folder.

But when I deploy to heroku I Got this Error:

> ```
> > 2021-09-14T09:21:44.381685+00:00 app[worker.1]: with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
> > 2021-09-14T09:21:44.381720+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secrets.json'
> ```

client_secrets.json:

```
{
   "web":{
      "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "project_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "redirect_uris":[
         "http://localhost:8080/",
         "http://localhost:8080/Callback"
      ],
      "javascript_origins":[
         "http://localhost"
      ]
   }
}
```

credentials.json:

```
{
   "access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "refresh_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "token_expiry":"2021-09-15T09:11:38Z",
   "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
   "user_agent":null,
   "revoke_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke",
   "id_token":null,
   "id_token_jwt":null,
   "token_response":{
      "access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "expires_in":3599,
      "refresh_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
      "token_type":"Bearer"
   },
   "scopes":[
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
   ],
   "token_info_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo",
   "invalid":false,
   "_class":"OAuth2Credentials",
   "_module":"oauth2client.client"
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library. Why are you trying to _save_ the credentials file? Heroku's ephemeral filesystem is likely to cause issues here.

Comment: @Chris Because these are credentials files that automatically authenticate and give access for users to access google drive contents

Comment: ...why does that mean you have to save them at runtime? If you're going to do that, you really should read up about [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) to make sure what you're trying to do won't break. Any changes you make to the local filesystem can be lost at any time, without notification.

Comment: @Chris yes i know that I'm searching to any method to use these credentials files on heroku

Comment: I don't have any context, but assuming losing those files (or changes to them) unpredictably isn't acceptable you'll have to save your state elsewhere. Perhaps in Redis?